# Дублирование записей, когда отправляется GET AJAX запрос

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Всем привет, такая проблема, имею код:

HTML:

```
<button id="more-news">Загрузить еще</button>
<script>
            var lng = '<?=$lang?>';
            var last_id = '<?php

                    $arr = end($front_page_news);

                    echo $arr['id'];

                ?>';
</script>
        <div id="responsecontainer">

        </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#more-news").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getnews.php",
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
    data: {
        lang: lng,
        last_id: last_id,
        limit: $(this).attr('data-lim'),
        ids: dataN
    },
    success: function(response){

        var content = document.getElementById("responsecontainer");
        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;

        //$("#responsecontainer").html(response);
        $('#more-news').attr('data-lim', Number($('#more-news').attr('data-lim')) + 10);
        //alert(response);
    }

});
```

PHP:

```html
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(\',\', $ids) . ") ORDER BY date_show DESC LIMIT '.$lim.' OFFSET 50');

//$q = $db->query('SELECT id, title_ru, title_md, body_ru, body_md, is_video, thumb_ru, thumb_md, date_show,title_ru, title_md
//FROM news GROUP BY id');

$lang = (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'ru') ? 'ru' : 'md';

$isHidden = false;

$cnt = 1;
if($q->num_rows > 0):
    foreach ($q as $item):
        $dtNews = new \DateTime($item['date_show']);


//        if (in_array($item['id'], $ids) || $dtNews > $dtNow) {
//            $isHidden = true;
//            break;
//        }


        $qs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news_categories WHERE news_id = " . $item['id']);
        if($qs->num_rows > 0) {
            $dd = $qs->fetch_assoc();



            $qss = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = " . $dd['categories_id']);
            $dd2 = $qss->fetch_assoc();


            if(in_array('Скрытые новости', $dd2) || in_array('Hidden News', $dd2)) {
                $isHidden = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        $dtShow = $dtNews->format("Y-m-d");
        //$dtShow = \Noitools\Utils::timeFromPost($item['date_show'], $lang);


        if($item['active'] == '1'):
            if($item['body_' . $lang] != ''):
                if(!$isHidden):
?>

        <div class="article-item" data-news="<?= $item['id']; ?>">
            <a href="/<?=$lang?>/news_id/<?=$item['id']?>"
               class="link-img-wrap<?= ($item['is_video']) ? ' video-icon-medium' : ''; ?>">
                <img src="/uploads/newsthumbs/760_500/<?=$item['id']?>.jpg"
                     alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="details-post">
                <i><?=$dtShow?></i>

                <a href="news_cat/<?= $dd2['id'] ?>" class="standard-hover-link"><?= $dd2['title_' . $lang] ?></a>


            </div>
            <h3><a href="/<?=$lang?>/news_id/<?=$item['id']?>"><span
                        class="detail-title"><?=$dtShow?></span> <?= $item['title_' . $lang] ?></a></h3>
            <p class="small-text">
                <?= mb_substr(strip_tags($item['body_' . $lang]), 0, 180,
                    'utf-8') ?>
            </p>
        </div>

<?php  endif; endif; endif; $cnt++; endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Почему-то у меня дублируются записи с бд, то есть нажимаю кнопку и выгружаются одни и те же записи. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Могу посоветовать redbeanphp или другую orm либу. 2017 год - PDO используют только для низкоуровнено подключения к БД.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите реализовать AJAX-подгрузку по `n` записей при нажатии на "кнопку"? Тогда подход и решение в корне не верны. Лучше почитайте статьи на тех же блогах, ибо решение не такое тривиальное, но если вкратце:

1. "Кнопка" должна содержать ссылку на постраничную навигацию, которая будет каждый раз меняться через JS, например, news.php?p=2).
2. При нажатии на нее уходит запрос на сервер посредством ajax'a.
3. Сервер берет переданное ему значение и лимитирует запрос на получение данных из таблицы, с обязательной проверкой на последнюю запись в ней, иначе можно в конце бесконечно нажимать на "кнопку" в надежде получить еще порцию записей.
4. Затем печатает вывод получившихся значений, который js выводит на странице под уже загруженными ранее записями.

Comment: $lim переменная итак есть и она меняется, посмотрите внимательнее код, но почему-то LIMIT $lim не работает

Comment: в смысле не подргружает данные

Comment: LIMIT принимает 2 значения - стартовую позицию и общее кол-во записей, необходимое для вывода. У Вас же получается, что он каждый раз возвращает `$lim` записей, а js Вам его не меняет (или Вы его не получаете обновленный и не передаете заново в скрипт)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что

1. значение переменной `last_id` присваивается один раз - при начальной загрузке страницы. Вам следует его обновлять после каждого вызова `$.ajax`;
2. параметр `last_id`, приходящий на сервер в вызове `ajax`, php кодом никак не используется.

Comment: как это можно сделать?

Comment: В том то и дело, что не используется, я его убрал, ибо негде его использовать